How can I solve this problem with clothes poking through each other on a daz figure while animating?
I've imported a daz figure with clothes using the daz to blender bridge during which I merged the clothes to the figure mesh as suggested in a tutorial. I'm very new to animating in blender, and I'm wondering how I can fix this issue with the clothes poking through each other as soon as I try to reposition the figure's leg? I can't see a way to manually correct the mesh on the clothes or to animate them separately? If someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks, Heather 

Hello it really depends on what you want to do with your character, how many actions do you plan to create, what will they be, etc? You could use shapekeys to correct the shape of the pants, or create bones to control some parts of your pants for example...

Hi, The sequence will be about 60 seconds of martial art/dance like moves. If there are any useful tutorials or resources I could study that someone could suggest that would be helpful.

maybe first look for a tutorial about shapekeys?

I'll look into it thanks

Ok I think this solution works best for my question so thank you Moonboots for suggesting shape keys. I realised that there is this sculpt button under the Daz to Blender tab, which allowed me to keyframe sculpting the clothes by pulling the mesh in and out and smoothing it with the sculpt tools. I did this on the time line when the leg was bent and again at a later keyframe when the leg was straightened again. I hope the image helps illustrate how to find this for someone else. As you can see the clothes no longer poke through each other! 
